# ¿Cómo puedo darle funcionalidad a botones creados con un bucle for en Python con tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

## Buenas noches.

Estoy haciendo una calculadora simple con tkinter y quiero crear los botones que representen los números y operadores con bucles.

Mi problema es que luego de crear los botones solo puedo acceder al último botón que se creó porque se sobreescriben.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    # -------- end number buttons configs --------
    self.rows = [["1", "2", "3"],
                 ["4", "5", "6"],
                 ["7", "8", "9"],
                 ["π", "0", "."]]

    # -------- Creating and positioning --------
    j=0
    for x, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        i=0
        for y, text in enumerate(row):
            self.btn = ttk.Button(self.frame_left_inf, text=text, style="Numbers.TButton", 
                                  command=lambda: self.insert(text))
            self.btn.place(relx=i, rely=j, relwidth=0.34, relheight=0.25)
            i+=0.33
        j+=0.25

    # -------- end number buttons configs --------

    # ------------- operator buttons configs -------------
    self.operators = [["*", "/"],
                      ["+", "-"],
                      ["DEL", "="]]


    # -------- Creating and positioning --------
    j=0
    for x, row in enumerate(self.operators):
        i=0
        for y, text in enumerate(row):
            self.btn = ttk.Button(self.frame_right_inf, text=text, style="Operators.TButton", 
                                  command=lambda: self.insert(text))
            self.btn.place(relx=i, rely=j, relwidth=0.50, relheight=0.34)
            i+=0.50
        j+=0.33
    # ------------- end operator buttons configs -------------
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa y presiono cualquier botón, lo único que se inserta en el cuadro de texto es el signo de "=", ya que fue el último en crearse.

Si alguien me puede ayudar, lo agradezco!

#### ¡Saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba almacenando self.btn en un diccionario, así no se pierden después del bucle, de esta manera:

```
self.botones = {}

# for ..
# .. for ..
    self.botones[text] = self.btn

# for ..
# .. for ..
    self.botones[text] = self.btn
```

Comment: Estimado, anteriormente había intentado realizar lo que tu me indicas pero no surte efecto alguno, también probé con almacenarlos en una lista pero tampoco.

Comment: @AlexisVelázquez Es raro que esa idea no te funcione. Recuerda que self.btn va a tener el ultimo boton creado. Para acceder a un boton especifico, tienes que acceder por su clave en el diccionario self.botones (por ejemplo self.botones["nombre_boton"])